# Pocketsphinx writing to console on word detection instead of waiting for silence

Tags: pocketsphinx

Currently the following command starts up pocketsphinx and waits for volume to hit a specific threshhold from the microphone, starts recording, and when the volume drops below the threshhold will start processing the recorded audio and output `hello` if the word was detected.

`pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes -keyphrase "hello" -kws_threshold 1e-30`

Due to environments that can be a tad noisy, waiting for that volume threshhold to drop can take longer then expected. Is there a way so Pocketsphinx will output recognizable words as they're being spoken without the need of waiting for silence?

Answer (score -1):

Overall if you have significant noise, it's better to cancel it with hardware somehow. Microphone array with source separation, directed beam microphone and so on should help you to reduce noise significantly. It is not a good idea to rely on pocketsphinx to deal with noise, it's not designed for that.

If you want immediate reaction on spotting, you'd better use pocketsphinx through API, not with pocketsphinx_continuous, this simple example in Python does what you want for example:

```
import sys, os, pyaudio
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *

modeldir = "../../../model"

# Create a decoder with certain model
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', os.path.join(modeldir, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-dict', os.path.join(modeldir, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))
config.set_string('-keyphrase', 'forward')
config.set_float('-kws_threshold', 1e+20)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
stream.start_stream()

# Process audio chunk by chunk. On keyphrase detected perform action and restart search
decoder = Decoder(config)
decoder.start_utt()
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
         decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
    else:
         break
    if decoder.hyp() != None:
        print ([(seg.word, seg.prob, seg.start_frame, seg.end_frame) for seg in decoder.seg()])
        print ("Detected keyphrase, restarting search")
        decoder.end_utt()
        decoder.start_utt()
```